# Implementing WebRTC on iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, verification

I am trying to build application for an iOS device using WebRTC. First of all I tried to build AppRTCDemo xcode project from https://github.com/gandg/webrtc-ios repository. Application runs but i am not getting desired output. When I join any room number I could only see nothing but a red screen. Also audio transmission was not working.

Then I tried building iOS example from Google's webRTC trunk using steps given in http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/. I followed all the steps but  I am facing application verification failed error while running ./makeall-iosdevice.sh file as follows.

```
Uploading AppRTCDemo.app package contents… DONE.
Installing ‘(null)’
Install – CreatingStagingDirectory (5%)
Install – ExtractingPackage (15%)
Install – InspectingPackage (20%)
Install – TakingInstallLock (20%)
Install – PreflightingApplication (30%)
Install – InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%)
Install – VerifyingApplication (40%)
Install – Error occured: ApplicationVerificationFailed
– launch complete
```

I have all the valid  certificates and provision profile included.

What I am missing? Could anyone please advice how to implement WebRTC on iOS device.

Comment: Yes please post the solution if someone is aware about the issue!

Comment: Did you find some solution? I found web browser from EricssonResearch but it's also buggy sometimes https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc

Comment: hiiii , can you guide me creating app based on webRTC in ios ?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same `ApplicationVerificationFailed` error when going through the steps mentioned in the [blogpost](http://ninjanetic.com/how-to-get-started-with-webrtc-and-ios-without-wasting-10-hours-of-your-life/).

First, specify your exact developer identity in the `build/common.gypi` file (this is described in the blogpost)

```
'CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]' : 'iPhone Developer: <your name> (<your id>)'
```

Then go to developer.apple.com and sign in with your developer account and create an App ID using the bundle ID of your choice. For me it was: 'hu.rumori.AppRTCDemo'.
You can specify anything, just make sure you use the same in the following steps.

Still on the Apple developer site create a new development provisioning profile for this App ID selecting your developer certificate and add the devices you want to test on.
Download the provisioning profile and add it to the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).
If you don't have it just download it from Apple it's quite useful.

After that update the `src/talk/examples/objc/AppRTCDemo/ios/info.plist` file to match the bundle ID you created above (this is also mentioned in the article)

Finally, delete everything in the `out_ios` directory to make sure the full build procedure is executed and run the build again:
`./build_apprtc.sh build_iosdevice`

To verify that the the proper provisioning profile is used just issue:

```
security cms -D -i src/out_ios/Release-iphoneos/AppRTCDemo.app/embedded.mobileprovision
```

You should see the bundle ID in the `application-identifier` property.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use **OpenTok SDK** to Implement WebRTC in iOS devices. I have also spent many hours in configuring the open sources project but didn't find any good/error free source code and than move to the paid library for one of my application that uses webRTC.

**Here is the link:** http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/ios/

Comment: OpenTok is suggested only of you have lots of money to give them. OpenTok not open source. But, its hard to find alternative for OpenTok.

Comment: OpenTok does not currently support arm64 :(